# Excel VBA: #REF! Find & Replace

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of functions that are all built off a variety of data sets and pivot tables.  During some of the data manipulation, one of the Tables is deleted and re-created.  This breaks several formulas that rely on that Table Name.

I am looking to find a way to search and replace in all formulas, using VBA, (keep in mind they are all slightly different) to replace #REF! with the term "DATASETNEW".

An example of one such formula is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,#REF!,4,FALSE)="12000"),"No Stock",VLOOKUP($A2,#REF!,5,FALSE))
```

Comment: If have to be in VBA: Loop through Formula of all UsedCells of all worksheets, either in memory (lot faster) or by Range, then change the formula accordingly.

Comment: ...any idea how I would do that?  I can loop through all cells with formulas and replace the entire formula, but I do not know how to replace just the #REF! text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeFormulas()
    Const LOOK_FOR As String = "#REF!"
    Const REPLACE_WITH As String = "DATASETNEW"
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, lCalcMode As Long
    Dim aFormulas As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, bHasLookFor As Boolean

    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Debug.Print "WORKSHEET", "ROW", "COLUMN", """" & LOOK_FOR & """?", "FORMULA"
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        aFormulas = oWS.UsedRange.Formula
        Select Case oWS.UsedRange.Cells.Count
            Case Is > 1
                For r = LBound(aFormulas, 1) To UBound(aFormulas, 1)
                    For c = LBound(aFormulas, 2) To UBound(aFormulas, 2)
                        bHasLookFor = (InStr(1, aFormulas(r, c), LOOK_FOR, vbTextCompare) > 0)
                        If bHasLookFor Then
                            Debug.Print oWS.Name, r, c, bHasLookFor, aFormulas(r, c)
                            oWS.UsedRange.Cells(r, c).Formula = Replace(aFormulas(r, c), LOOK_FOR, REPLACE_WITH)
                        End If
                    Next c
                Next r
            Case 1
                bHasLookFor = (InStr(1, aFormulas, LOOK_FOR, vbTextCompare) > 0)
                If bHasLookFor Then
                    Debug.Print oWS.Name, 1, 1, bHasLookFor, aFormulas
                    oWS.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Formula = Replace(aFormulas, LOOK_FOR, REPLACE_WITH)
                End If
        End Select
    Next oWS
    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode
End Sub
```

This will loop through all worksheets in the workbook, look for and replace those string if required. It displays the progress on Immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace (Ctrl+H) will update them within the formula.

Comment: Yeah.  I really would like to do it programmatically.